# How do I purge a linux mail box with huge number of emails?

Tags: email, purge

I have setup some cron jobs and they send the crons result to an email. Now over the months I have accumulated a huge number of emails.

Now my question is how can I purge all those emails from my mailbox?

Comment: In case you want to clean only the cron messages and not other messages, see here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/217143/how-to-clean-a-flooded-mailbox

Comment: Closed as off-topic, but hugely useful.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

You can simply delete the `/var/mail/username` file to delete all emails for a specific user. Also, emails that are outgoing but have not yet been sent will be stored in `/var/spool/mqueue`.

Comment: The email at question which receive all cron emails is say cron_results@site.com. I just want to purge all the emails received on this email, leaving others intact. deleting the /var/www/username will delete all, right?

Comment: `username` has to be replaced with the user for which you'd like to remove the emails. In your case, the emails are being sent to the user called `cron_results`, so you would have to delete `/var/www/cron_results`.

Comment: It is not a good praxis data manipulation from outside an application. If there is an option or command that can do the job, it is better to use it. As @timaschew answered, you can use the ‘d’ command inside the mail tool.

Comment: Very practical when 'mail' only responds with 'Not enough memory - Aborted'.

Comment: Wow my mailbox was 36 GB (cronjob logs). Thanks that saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Another way is to type `> /var/spool/mail/root`

Answer (score 492):

alternative way:

```
mail -N
d *
quit
```

`-N` Inhibits the initial display of message headers when reading mail or editing a mail folder.
`d *` delete all mails

Comment: does not work on Debian 7.

Comment: If the mailbox file (/var/mail/<user>) is too large, the mail command would take forever to load and might een fill up /tmp, resulting in failure.  Much easier to just delete the aforementioned file.

Comment: It worked for me in nearly vanilla Debian 7.5. Alternatively one may want to delete all saved mails with simply typing `> mbox` in home directory, this just truncates mbox file.

Comment: @andreas : just add it working successfully on CentOS 6.5.

Comment: Also worked for me on Debian Wheezy (7.6)

Comment: working on Ubuntu 14.04 server

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 16.04 server

Comment: Worked on CentOS 7

Comment: Don't know how you got it to work on Centos 7. I'm on 7.1 and there is no `mail` command.

Comment: Super answer. Thank you! CentOS 7 here.

Comment: best solution. Even the official instructions of -d ALL didn't work on my Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: If it doesn't work, do you write `quit`? Without it the result isn't saved, i.e. messages won't be deleted.

Comment: @LeonidMednikov That's it! Typing `exit` instead of `quit` does not persist the delete.

Comment: Works on Debian 9.2 and as before stated, `quit` is important!

Comment: that is the best answer (for Ubuntu users)

Comment: @Ethereal: I had this because somehow root got a mailbox of over 5GiB large and I was running out of disk space whilst loading said mailbox using the mail command. Sigkilled the mail command and manually deleted the file worked for me.

Answer (score 75):

Just use:

```
mail
d 1-15
quit
```

Which will delete all messages between number 1 and 15.  to delete all, use the `d *`.

I just used this myself on ubuntu 12.04.4, and it worked like a charm.

For example:

```
eric@dev ~ $ mail
Heirloom Mail version 12.4 7/29/08.  Type ? for help.
"/var/spool/mail/eric": 2 messages 2 new
>N  1 Cron Daemon           Tue Jul 29 17:43  23/1016  "Cron <eric@ip-10-0-1-51> /usr/bin/php /var/www/sandbox/eric/c"
 N  2 Cron Daemon           Tue Jul 29 17:44  23/1016  "Cron <eric@ip-10-0-1-51> /usr/bin/php /var/www/sandbox/eric/c"
& d *
& quit
```

Then check your mail again:

```
eric@dev ~ $ mail
No mail for eric
eric@dev ~ $
```

What is tripping you up is you are using `x` or `exit` to quit which rolls back the changes during that session.

Comment: There is no space between `d*`, at least on `CentOS 7`.

Comment: Using `exit` rather than `quit` was tripping me up. `exit` will abort the session, so any emails pending deletion are left intact. `quit` will write the changes back, so deleted emails are committed at that point.

Comment: `d 1-15` works on Debian 8. Thanks!

Comment: Does not work in Red Hat. d 1-15 gives out 'Illegal numeric'. So does d *.

Answer (score 29):

One liner:

```
echo 'd *' | mail -N
```

Comment: In HP-UX box, mail has no -N options. But, `yes 'd' |  mail` works as expected.

Answer (score 26):

Rather than deleting, I think we can nullify the file, because the file will be created if the mail service is still on.
Something like following will do the job

```
cat /dev/null >/var/spool/mail/tomlinuxusr
```

And yes, sorry for awakening this old thread but I felt I could contribute.

Comment: Also for the lazy, just typing this works too: >/var/spool/mail/unixuser

Answer (score 9):

On UNIX / Linux / Mac OS X you can copy and override files, can't you? So how about this solution:

```
cp /dev/null /var/mail/root
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using cyrus/sasl/imap on your mailserver, then one fast and efficient way to purge everything in a mailbox that is older then number of days specified is to use cyrus/imap **ipurge** command. For example, here is an example removing everything (be carefull!!), older then 30 days from user *vleo*. Notice, that you must be logged in as *cyrus* (imap mail administrator) user:

`[cyrus@mailserver ~]$ /usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/ipurge -f  -d 30 user.vleo
Working on user.vleo...
total messages           4
total bytes              113183
Deleted messages         0
Deleted bytes            0
Remaining messages       4
Remaining bytes          113183`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than use "d", why not "p".  I am not sure if the "p *" will work.  I didn't try that.  You can; however use the following script"

```
#!/bin/bash
#

MAIL_INDEX=$(printf 'h a\nq\n' | mail | egrep -o '[0-9]* unread' | awk '{print $1}')

markAllRead=
for (( i=1; i<=$MAIL_INDEX; i++ ))
do
   markAllRead=$markAllRead"p $i\n"
done
markAllRead=$markAllRead"q\n"
printf "$markAllRead" | mail
```

Comment: For those who are curious, "p" is short for "print".